# Query in ascending order based on the number of occurances of numbers in a column

Tags: regex, database, oracle

I have to write a query where I need to fetch the data from a table sorting on a varchar column based on number of occurrences of numbers in the column values

Ex:

### Data

`abc123bcsAny
edef2323sdfhsk3212
shdfks`

Here if I try to fetch it in ascending order, it should give me the result as

`shdfks
abc123bcsAny
edef2323sdfhsk3212`

Can you help in writing this query?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
with test as(
select 'abc123bcsAny' string from dual union all
select 'edef2323sdfhsk3212' from dual union all
select 'shdfks' from dual
)
select *
from test
order by regexp_count(string, '[0-9]')
```

Answer (score 1):

To order by the count of the number sub-strings within the string:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY REGEXP_COUNT( data, '\d+' ) ASC
```